# What is the content_type for WebVtt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, content-type, webvtt

I'd like to allow my application to permit .vtt files on upload. Right now it was only accepting .txt files, but I'd like to add .vtt capability for captions.

I've tried this *with no luck:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :caption, 
  :content_type => ['application/txt', 'text/plain', 'WEBVTT', 'application/vtt', 'vtt']
```

What is the proper format in this case?

Comment: The MIME type for WebVTT is `text/vtt`: https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/#webvtt-file

Comment: didn't work. any ideas?

Comment: WebVTT is a very new standard, and so a very new MIME type. Rails might not know about it yet. You may have to just check the extension or come up with your own validation by checking the actual data [against the spec](https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/#webvtt-file-body).

Answer (score 12):

The MIME type for WebVTT caption files is `text/vtt` as specified in https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/#iana-text-vtt